# Change slider after clicking on the option to choose the color

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider, gallery

I would like to implement change slider after clicking on product color option in my product site. It should be similar to here, but not a static image, but slider. Website is based on Wordpress. I am looking for plugin slider and JS/jQuery function to make change slider after clicking.

Comment: drop the html and js here if you have any, if you don't have then your on the wrong site

Answer (score 1):

You can go through link http://imageslidermaker.com/blog/how-to-make-a-responsive-image-slider-using-jquery-and-css which helps to create an Image slider using jQuery and CSS.